# List keeps getting same first value, even though value changes

Tags: c#, list, int, addition

I'm writing an encryptor code and to be more specific:
I'm currently writing a check that encrypts the letters and then decrypts them in order to see whether they can be, and then compares the decrypted output to the initial input.
I check this because the decryption formula uses `cos^-1` which can't take use values.

Unfortunately, the list of the ints of the letters `(a=1, b=2, z=26, etc)` keeps adding the same first value, even though the value changes.

Part of the code:

```
foreach(int x in LetInt) {
    DoubInt++;

    try {
        CheckLetInt.Add(Convert.ToInt64(Math.Acos(Math.Pow((((Math.Tan((x+1) / (180/Math.PI)) / Math.Sin((x+1) / (180/Math.PI))) * (Math.Cos(A / (180/Math.PI)) * B)) - 1) / (Math.Cos(A / (180 / Math.PI)) * B), -1)) * (180 / Math.PI)));
        Console.WriteLine("Correct number:" + Convert.ToInt64(Math.Acos(Math.Pow((((Math.Tan((x+1) / (180/Math.PI)) / Math.Sin((x+1) / (180/Math.PI))) * (Math.Cos(A / (180/Math.PI)) * B)) - 1) / (Math.Cos(A / (180 / Math.PI)) * B), -1)) * (180 / Math.PI)));
        Console.WriteLine("List content:" + CheckLetInt[DoubInt - 1]);
        CheckLetter.Add(LetPos[Convert.ToInt64(CheckLetInt[DoubInt - 1]) - 1]);
    } catch(Exception) {
        ValueError.Visible = true;
        ClearAll();
        Console.WriteLine("Caught.");
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Anyone know what's going on?
The "Correct Number" and "List Content" formulae are the same.

[Link to the project (it's a program so the code by itself doesn't work)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12vdPxJl1IUA5wIhK_ldFgXjPLQA72sxp)

[Link to the code by itself](https://code.sololearn.com/cr8IAup7PIBP/#cs)

Comment: can you please pull all the necessary code to replicate the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand you question, but are you trying to 'encrypt' text, one letter at a time, using trigonometry...?

Comment: Where is DoubInt defined? You must be not incrementing it properly

Comment: @Milney Correct. I'm taking the int of every letter and putting each of them though a formula. Then I add or subtract 26 until I reach a value between 1 and 26 again and output the new letter and the amount of times 26 has been added or subtracted. DoubInt is defined as a static int and it's being defined correctly, I think, because the "Correct Output" value is correct and for the rest without this one check the code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later down in the loop you do:

```
if(string.Join("", CheckLetter) == string.Join("", Letters.ToArray())) {
     ...
} else {
     ClearAll();
}
```

You never modify Letters in loop, but you do modify CheckLetter, so this will mostly return false, calling the ClearAll() method.

In ClearAll() you set DoubInt back to zero - hence always showing the first entry

```
        DoubInt = 0;
```

Note that this is not a good way to 'encrypt' anything. If you are just playing around then okay, but if you are trying to learn cryptography you should read up on same basics first if you think this is 'encryption'